# Javascript For loop like Python

Tags: javascript

I am a programing newbie and usually use Python but have found myself needing to use Javascript  for this project (phonegap).

i retrieve the following query from a server

```
`[["CompanyName", "lat", "long", ID, "street", 6.8], ["CompanyName", "lat", "long", ID, "street", 23.7]]`
```

In Python i get would do the following to print CompanName for each entry.

```
for x in r.json():
        print x[0]
```

How would i achieve the same thing in Javascript?

when i retrieve the query if i try to loop through it, it iterates every character of the query as a string. so i try the following:

```
var result = xmlhttp.responseText;
result = eval("("+ result +")");
```

i loop through it with:

```
for (var i in result) 
                {
                    display +="<br/>" + result[i];}
```

How would i specify just the CompanyName like in the Python example?

`

Comment: Read [3. Use for-in correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-in-an-array-how-to-do-that-in-javascript/9329476#9329476)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this `result[i][0]` since it's a nested array.

```js
var result = [["CompanyName1", "lat", "long", "ID", "street", 6.8],["CompanyName2", "lat", "long", "ID", "street", 23.7]];

var div = document.getElementById('result');

for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    div.innerHTML += ("<br/>" + result[i][0]);
}
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CecYL/)